# Switch Users through for gitHub through terminal

Tags: github

What is the proper way to switch between Accounts through GitHub terminal without compromising code or Account information ? For example: I use "Account1" for personal projects, and "Account2" for school projects.

Comment: Note you should **not** have two personal accounts because it's a violation of the GitHub terms. For your school projects you can easily create an organization.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But is it possible to switch between accounts? What if two individuals use the same computer?

Comment: Ideally there should be two operating system users then. Another solution is to use per-repository authentication (e.g. using tokens in the remote urls).